# What is facilitiy fee in islam

Tags: interest, sharia-financing

Ethio telecom offer credit to his customer with rate of facility fee repayed at fixed date and also fee with daily charge. Is there a diffrence between the two term mean facility fee(service charge) and daily fee? Is that both are interest and prohibited such that i may in state of RIBA

Comment: “Fee with daily charge” looks a whole lot like simple interest to me…

Comment: Is this what you're asking about: https://www.ethiotelecom.et/mela-micro-credit/

Comment: @keshlam It is a religious question in the sense that Islam prohibits charging (or paying) interest.

Comment: You might get better answers on a Stack focused more specifically on Islamic law.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (coming from a country with a large Muslim population, but not being Muslim myself), these fees are a sort-of work-around for companies which would like to charge you interest (and may do so to non-Muslim customers), but want to remain at least technically compliant with sharia law.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better asked (and get better answers) in the Islam Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Should absolutely not be closed. This is about money.

Comment: I have placed some savings with an Islamic bank in my Western country, (I am not a Muslim) and at the moment I am getting 4.62 per cent 'profit', paid monthly. My Muslim colleague recommended it to me. We are both very happy.

Answer (score 3):

“RIBA” in the Muslim religion is charging excessive interest, say 5% a month. Which would be illegal for example in totally non-Islamic German law as well. The difference is that Islam doesn’t set a fixed rate for what is legal and what is illegal, making basically any interest impossible.

Two things happen: First, by calling it a “fee” it’s not interest anymore and therefore becomes legal. Unless the fees are excessive. Ask any non-Muslim friend whether they think the fees are excessive. For example if your friend received a mortgage paying five percent interest a year, you can’t take that mortgage because it charges interest. A mortgage charging a five percent per year “fee” would be fine. A mortgage charging a five percent per month fee would be usury, and a Christian friend would call it that.

Answer (score -1):

They are different names for essentially the same thing - a service fee for having a line of credit.  For example, if you make use of an overdraft, the bank might charge a daily fee for the use of the overdraft facility on the account.

The important thing is that these fees are *not* interest.  Interest is calculated as a percentage of the amount borrowed.  This is a fixed fee for a service.

Comment: [In this case](https://www.ethiotelecom.et/mela-micro-credit/) the fees indeed appear to be a percentage of the amount borrowed.